# Check given user's listItem permissions with SharePoint 2010 Managed Client Object Model (c#)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

Is it possible to determine if a user can access a given item identified by its url without the users context - it has to be done with CSOM.

Code so far:

```
var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relative);
clientContext.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var listitem = file.ListItemAllFields;
clientContext.Load(listitem, f => f.RoleAssignments.Include(r => r.RoleDefinitionBindings, r => r.Member), f => f.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(user)); // <= this line breaks it
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = listitem.RoleAssignments;
```

Or with another call:

```
bool hasPermissions = false;
var roleAssignment = roleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(user); // <= breaks
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


foreach (RoleDefinition role in roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
{
    hasPermissions = role.BasePermissions.Has(PermissionKind.Open);

    if (hasPermissions) break;
}
```

I tried many combinations but every time I use **GetByPrincipal** I get an exception. Any pointers?

Comment: I assume you can only see the item permissions in an elevated context (this excludes CSOM)- a confirmation would be great.

Comment: couldn't you use the credentials of an admin account for this action or is this not an option? `clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");`

Comment: you also could use    permissionMask = new BasePermissions(); permissionMask.Set(PermissionKind.Open); listitem.DoesUserHavePermissions(permissionMask);

Comment: Max, both Dolgsthrasir and ReTech are correct.  It looks like the account that you are executing the code might not have the proper permission in this case.  If you post the text of the exception here, we can confirm that.  Your options are as already advised, to elevate your credentials or ensure that your ID already has access.